# Identify application that created a certain IGMP join request?

Tags: ip, multicast

Is there a way to find from which application a certain "Group Record" came from in an IGMPv3 packet?

We are trying to figure the application that added the IGMP request to include source as local loopback. Please see the below screenshot.

[image: Wireshark view of Group Records in the IGMP packet.]

Also in the above screenshot, we can see 3 group records. Does the kernel bundle group records from different applications?

I learned that an application can set the options to indicate to create "Mode Is Include" requests from an application as explained at https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt and https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip